# Fetching google results + result description

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have the following code below, which works except I am unable to figure out how to retrieve the description of results. I've tried several different divs and it doesn't appear to work. Can someone please help? What is the proper div to grab with soup.find_all for data_descr?

```s
    q = '+'.join(q.split())
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + q + '&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers_Get)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    #print (soup.prettify())
    data_text = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd'})
    data_link = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'kCrYT'})
    data_descr = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'}) #select(".s3v9rd.AP7Wnd")
    print (data_descr)
```

Answer (score 0):

for description you select right div with class you have to just get the text like this

```
desciption_div = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'})
for desciption in desciption_div:
    dscrpt = desciption.get_text()
    print(dscrpt)
```

but remember this divs have span tag also where these text actually present but only these text are present so using direct on div.

Comment: `data_descr = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc'}) #select(".s3v9rd.AP7Wnd")
    for desc in data_descr:
        print (desc.get_text())` Doesnt work...

Comment: it's working fine for me . check the response `soup.prettify()` if it in there